# bash echo into another file not working

Tags: linux, bash

I want to append a line to another file from within my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "xxx" >> ~/.bashrc
```

However I get:

```
bash: xxx: command not found
```

Comment: Add the output of `cat -A your_script` to the question. Whatever follows `echo` is taken as `echo`'s argument, so unless there is some weird encoding (may be line ending) issue, this is not reproducible.

Comment: Can you check your bash alias? (execute __alias__ )

Comment: I think it should be line ending issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it (the `echo "xxx" >>` part) from the CLI. It is likely caused by an improper file format (e.g. wrong encoding and/or windows line endings.

Also `cat -a SCRIPTNAME` might give some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Could be it already worked, now you have an `xxx` command a the end of your `~/.bashrc` and the next time it (bash) is invoked, it runs your `.bashrc` but can't find `xxx`. Is there an `xxx` command in your `PATH`?